# Sending Test Sends using the Undocumented REST API using DE ROW PREVIEW

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I was looking at [Gortonington's blog on Sending Test Sends using the Undocumented REST API](https://gortonington.com/email-send-preview-and-test-sends-via-rest-api) and attempted to do a test send using the using DE ROW PREVIEW example but got a 400 Bad Request error.

I'm wondering if this has changed in the last year since it this was written (unofficially).

Using details about my Data Extension {{deid}} (I assume this means Data Extension's External Key), SendClassificationID, deliveryProfileID, senderProfileID, the emailID, and my test recipient email address I plugged in the following...

(1) I'm sure I'm using the correct sendClassificationID value as it has worked on other REST API calls.
(2) The Data Extension is an active one...I'm sure USED FOR TESTING and USED FOR SENDING has been checked (marked as YES) on the test data extension and I can do manual send previews and test sends/actual sends based on regular Send Previews from the SFMC interface.
(3) I'm going by the "DE ROW PREVIEW" example and not the "Contact Key" example so I don't believe {{deid}} is the ContactKey but instead the ExternalKey id. Also, I tried to actual name of the Data Extension to see if that worked and got the same error so I went back to the External Key value for {{deid}}. As such, I used the the number 1 for the row id (integer) to indicate I want to do a test send on the first row.

```
{
   "dataSource": {
   "id": "key:{{fb4d12f1-948e-ec11-b839-d4f5ef03544a}}",
   "row": 1,
   "type": "DataExtension"
},
   "emailID": "527972",
   "isMultipart": true,
   "options": {
   "EnableETURLs": "true"
},
   "recipients": [
   "test@email.com"
],
    "sendManagement": {
    "sendClassificationID": "e64d31d2-db9c-e011-98ea-1cc1de7487fc",
    "deliveryProfileID": "e44d31d2-db9c-e011-98ea-1cc1de7487fc",
    "senderProfileID": "6879408e-a3a1-e011-98ea-1cc1de7487fc"
},
    "subjectPrefix": "[Test]:",
    "suppressTracking": true,
    "trackLinks": true
}
```

The 404 Bad Request error shows the following Response...

```
{
"message": "Unable to generate test send.",
"errorcode": 10006,
"documentation": "",
"validationErrors": [
    {
        "message": "The SendClassification ID is not valid.",
        "errorcode": 10005,
        "documentation": ""
    },
    {
        "message": "The Data Extension must be active to send a preview email.",
        "errorcode": 10000,
        "documentation": ""
    },
    {
        "message": "The Data Extension must be marked sendable to send a preview email.",
        "errorcode": 10005,
        "documentation": ""
    },
    {
        "message": "A contact id (integer), contact key (string), or row id (integer) must be provided to send a preview email.",
        "errorcode": 10002,
        "documentation": ""
    }
]
```

}

Comment: DEID is the guid ID given to a de upon creation. This is read only. It is not the name or key but a third data point.

Comment: Where can I retrieve this read-only guid ID specific to an existing DE? I looked at the properties on the Data Extension object and didn't see it and the only other read-only property I saw was 'ID' but the SOAP API won't allow retrieve's on it. You mention it's given upon creation of a DE...does that mean I need to create a new DE from scratch with the API with the desired fields in order to see this guid? I thought it'd semi-visible somewhere in SFMC UI...like a right click to a new window. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html

Comment: This is the simplest way (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325467&type=1), but you can retrieve it from the API as well. I believe it is called the 'ObjectID' or similar.

Comment: I retrieved the 'ObjectID' using SOAP API on Data Extension name/ExternalKey and retried the updated call I just updated my question with. Unfortunately, it still throws the 400 Bad Request Error Either a valid DataExtension ID (Guid) or CustomerKey (string) must be provided to send a preview email. I saw someone suggest using key:{{}} as a prefix. Is the syntax not correct?

Comment: Also, I followed the 2 approaches and got 2 different numbers...ObjectID retrieved from the SOAP API was different from the CustomObjectID retrieved from the right-click copy link to notepad approach. In both cases I got the same error message when trying both id's both with key:{{deid}} and without key prefix but with the key:{{}} it showed only the bottom error.. A contact id (integer), contact key (string), or row id (integer) must be provided to send a preview email.

Comment: are you using `/guide/v1/emails/preview/send`? I am not positive what you are seeing with `key:{{deid}}` inside of it. Also you need to verify the row number is valid as that sounds like what is the issue in your example error response, not the DE

Comment: I just ran a test on that endpoint and it worked with the GUID DE ID I grabbed through the method shared above without issue. Another way to validate (judging off of your mention it works in UI) is to go to where you do the send test. Push F12 to open dev tools, go to the 'network' tab then click the 'send test' button in the UI. In that tab it should show the same API call as what I have listed and it will show the payload in there that it used. You can then compare what you have to that and validate what the issue could be.